# calculate duration in a complex table_1

Tags: r, date, duration

I have a data frame

```
df <- data.frame("name" = c("jack", "william", "david", "john"),
                 "01-Jan-19" = c(NA,"A", NA,"A"),
                 "01-Feb-19" = c("A","A",NA,"A"),
                 "01-Mar-19" = c("S","A","A","A"),
                 "01-Apr-19" = c("A","A","A","S"),
                 "01-May-19" = c(NA,"A","A","A"),
                 "01-Jun-19" = c("A","S","A","S"),
                 "01-Jul-19" = c("A","S","A","S"),
                 "01-Aug-19" = c(NA,"S","A","A"),
                 "01-Sep-19" = c(NA,"S","A","S"),
                 "01-Oct-19" = c("S","S","A","S"),
                 "01-Nov-19" = c("S","S",NA,"S"),
                 "01-Dec-19" = c("S","S","S",NA),
                 "01-Jan-20" = c("S","M","A","M"),
                 "01-Feb-20" = c("M","M","M","M"))
```

To calculate the duration for each person between the first A to the last A, I was able to achieve with the following

```
duration <- df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'person', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(person = dmy(sub('X', '', person))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(avg_duration = person[max(which(value == 'A'))] - person[min(which(value == 'A'))])
```

May I ask how to modify the codes for the following purpose?
of periods in between the two As, how can I minus the period that are with other values (anything that is not A, e.g. S, NA)?
Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. For example, `Jack` has a set of `A` values from `2019-02-01` to `2019-07-01`, but with an `S` in `2019-03-01`. What is your expected output? Would a simple `count()` of the `A` values suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have difficulty understanding what a period means in this case. It seems from your example, that you need two values for a period. Is this also the case for the periods to subtract? If, e.g., a person has the series: A, S, A, do they have 0, 1 or 2 periods with A? and what about A, S, A, A, S, A ?

If instead each date represents a period, that is valid until the next date, the total duration for each person-value combination can be calculated as follows:

```
duration <- df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'date') %>%
  dplyr::mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(sub('X', '', date))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(name, date) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(duration = c(diff(date), 0)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(name, value) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(summed_duration = sum(duration))
```

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   name [4]
   name    value summed_duration
   <chr>   <chr> <drtn>         
 1 david   A     276 days       
 2 david   M       0 days       
 3 david   S      31 days       
 4 david   NA     89 days       
 5 jack    A     119 days       
 6 jack    M       0 days       
 7 jack    S     154 days       
 8 jack    NA    123 days       
 9 john    A     152 days       
10 john    M      31 days       
11 john    S     182 days       
12 john    NA     31 days       
13 william A     151 days       
14 william M      31 days       
15 william S     214 days
```

**Edit according to comment**

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'date') %>%
  dplyr::mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(sub('X', '', date))) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(name, date) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(duration = c(diff(date), 0)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(name, value) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() < dplyr::last(dplyr::row_number()) | value != 'A') %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(summed_duration = sum(duration)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(value == 'A')

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   name [4]
  name    value summed_duration
  <chr>   <chr> <drtn>         
1 david   A     245 days       
2 jack    A      88 days       
3 john    A     121 days       
4 william A     120 days
```

Comment: To clarify: e.g. Jack, first A is 01 Feb 19, last A is 01 July 19, but Mar and May are not A, so the duration should be total number of days between 01 Feb 19 and 01 July 19, minus 62 days (Mar + May). Is this doable? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can do this just by removing the last duration for each group. I have edited the answer to include this. It seems a bit weird, that A's represent time points, while S's and NA's represents periods of 1 month. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. it is not intentional, as A, S, NA represent a title in that period. If I calculate duration between two S, the periods in between which have titles A, NA will need to removed. The revised codes work.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate max index and minimum index where `value = 'A'` for each
`name` and subtract the number of days in month in between them where `value` is not `'A'`.

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name,names_to = 'person', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(person = lubridate::dmy(sub('X', '', person))) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(min_ind = min(which(value == 'A')), 
                   max_ind = max(which(value == 'A')), 
                   duration = person[max_ind] - person[min_ind] - 
             sum(lubridate::days_in_month(person[value[min_ind:max_ind] != 'A'])))


#  name    min_ind max_ind duration
#  <chr>     <int>   <int> <drtn>  
#1 david         1      10 275 days
#2 jack          1       5  89 days
#3 john          1       8  90 days
#4 william       1       5 120 days
```

Comment: John has 120/121 days depending on whether you include the last day.